# Unable to take a Screenshot image (Selenium Tests) on Ubuntu (AWS) but same code works on a Windows machine?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, selenium, ubuntu, jenkins

Currently I'am attempting to take a screenshot image when a failure occurs (Running tests on a Ubuntu AWS instance).

My code:

```
WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(getDriver());
File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot)augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(screenshotFile, new File("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/efesfe.png"));
```

Also tried to create a text file on the ubuntu desktop which also doesnt work:

```
File fout = new File("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/myOutFile.txt");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
bw.write("Write somthing to the file ...");
bw.newLine();
bw.close();
```

Please note I'am triggering my tests via Jenkins which is hosted on the Ubuntu instance.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have write access to `/home/ubuntu/Desktop`?

Comment: What is the error? Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @supputuri thanks for the comment, I tried to alter permissions for the desktop using sudo chown, the issue seems very odd, whilst Jenkins is able to create a text file and write it to the desktop, the java program is unable to even through its being compiled by Jenkins. Also there seems to be no exception messages being outputted to the console window via Jenkins.